# Using "r" with variables in re.sub

Tags: python, regex

I need to do this:

```
text = re.sub(r'\]\n', r']', text)
```

But with `find` and `replace` as variables:

```
find = '\]\n'
replace = ']'
text = re.sub(find, replace, text)
```

Where should I put `r` (raw)? It is not a string.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `r''` is part of the [string literal syntax](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literals):

```
find = r'\]\n'
replace = r']'
text = re.sub(find, replace, text)
```

The syntax is in no way specific to the `re` module. However, specifying regular expressions is one of the main use cases for raw strings.

Comment: @Qiao: Using `r''` raw literals makes specifying a regular expression easier. It is not a requirement to use them.

Comment: @Qiao: Nope. See the documentation link I've added to my answer.

Answer (score 5):

Short answer: you should keep the `r` together with the string.

The `r` prefix is part of the string syntax. With `r`, Python doesn't interpret backslash sequences such as `\n`, `\t` etc inside the quotes. Without `r`, you'd have to type each backslash twice in order to pass it to `re.sub`.

```
r'\]\n'
```

and

```
'\\]\\n'
```

are two ways to write same string.

Answer (score 2):

Keep `r'...'`

```
find = r'\]\n'
replace = r']'
text = re.sub(find, replace, text)
```

or go with

```
find = '\\]\\n'
replace = ']'
text = re.sub(find, replace, text)
```